# jQuery - identifying specific form data when there multiple forms

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a page with multiple forms on it each containing one submit button. When the button is pressed, I need to use the data from various hidden elements on the form.

Passing the data via Ajax is working for me using code like this...

```
$("body").on("submit", "form", function (event) {
          var pm = $(this).serialize();
          event.preventDefault();
          $.post(
            'urota3.php?' + pm
             )
.....
```

The data for the correct form is passed to urota3 and all is well.
BUT...
I also need to use that data in the event function and I'm not sure how to get at it. I had tried adding a data section like this....

```
$("body").on("submit", "form", {
  id: $('input:hidden[name=id]').val()
}, function (event) {...
```

but of course that picks up the data from the first form on the pade, not the one whose button you pressed.
How can I reference a piece of data from the correct form?
Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("body").on("submit", "form", function (event) {
      var pm = $(this).serialize();
      pm[id] = $(this).find('input:hidden[name='+id+']').val();
      event.preventDefault();
      $.post(
        'urota3.php?' + pm
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $(this) within the event function and search for your input from there ...